# Move or rename subfolders

Tags: centos, files, directory, rename

I have a folder structure like this:

```
/ms/files/a/
/fb/files/a/
/db/files/a/
```

It should be like this:

```
/ms/files/b/
/fb/files/b/
/db/files/b/
```

I can find the folders I need to move or rename using

```
find . -path "*/files/a" -type d
```

But how do I rename the results?

Comment: Is the leading directory always one level deep, or do you need the `find` because there's, for example, `/ms/other/directory/files/a`?

Comment: It's always one level deep

Comment: Found it: should use the full path and * as wildcard. Thanx for your help @JeffSchaller!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
for d in /*/files/a/
do
  mv "$d" "${d%a/}b"
done
```

... which uses `*` to match all of the initial "client" top-level directories, followed by the required `/files/a/` subdirectory structure. It then uses parameter expansion to strip the trailing `a/` off of each one and then "replace" it with a `b` for the rename.

Comment: Thanks! But... I get an error: mv: cannot stat `?/files/a/': No such file or directory. When I use a hardcoded path it works, problem seems with the ?

Comment: I used the "/client" portion from your question, where I assumed that each "client" directory had a single digit after it. Are those your actual directory names?

Comment: Also: the /client1/ part is the name of a client (e.g. /microsoft/files/a, /google/files/a, etc).

Comment: Then I was inadvertently distracted by the similar pattern. Could you edit the question to describe the commonalities & differences in the files /directories you want to match? Thanks!

Comment: @Lennart, I've reworked the answer given the actual directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky solution:

```
eval $(find . -path "*/files/a" -type d -print | xargs -n1 -exec echo | sed 's/\(.*\/\)\(.*\)$/mv \1\2 \1b;/')
```

Sed creates the arguments for the mv command. The output is then eval'ed.

If we remove `eval $()`, it looks like this executed on three test folders in the path:

```
$ find . -path "*/files/a" -type d -print | xargs -n1 -exec echo | sed 's/\(.*\/\)\(.*\)$/mv \1\2 \1b;/'
mv ./client1/files/a ./client1/files/b;
mv ./client2/files/a ./client2/files/b;
mv ./client3/files/a ./client3/files/b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by below method and it worked fine

```
for i in /ms/files/  /fb/files/ /db/files/; do find $i -type d; done| sed -n '/a$/p'| awk '{print "sudo mv" " " $1 " " substr($1,1,10)"b/"}'|sh
```